# problems in inserting spanish words in oracle db

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

Is there a way to insert spanish words into the Oracle table - like 'España'.

When I try to insert it, it either takes the ASCII counterpart of it or replaces the 'ñ' with a '?'.

Has anyone done this before or knows a work around for it?

I found something while googling they told we have to mention spanish character set in init.ora file. I don't know how to do this and also setting  nls_settings for client. I am using toad to connect to server which is located in UK.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: What is the database character set (`select * from v$nls_parameters`)?  What is the `NLS_LANG` setting on the client?  What do you get if you `SELECT dump(column_name, 1016), column_name FROM table_name WHERE <<some predicate that returns just the row of interest>>'?

Comment: These are the details NLS_CHARACTER_SET  WE8ISO8859P9
NLS_LANGUAGE       AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY      AMERICA

Comment: OK.  What is the `NLS_LANG` on the client?  And what does the query I posted return?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check if the database was created with a character set that includes the Spanish characters that you want inserted. For versions of Oracle starting with 9i the wizards by default create the database using Unicode, so it shouldn't be a problem. But if the database wasn't created by you, this should be the first thing to check with the DBA that created it.

Which version of the Oracle server are you connecting to?

Which version of the Oracle client are you using? Which kind of Oracle client (OCI, JDBC, .NET)?

If the database was properly created it can be a problem related to the client platform.

And this is not simple to diagnose without information about the client OS, database client libraries that you are using and their configurations related to Natural Language Support.

So, I will point you to an Oracle FAQ related to this issue. It is a lot of material to read but it worths your time.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html